# Glassfish port unification causes web service deployment exception

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, ejb, ear

After applying port unification to my glassfish domain using the following commands

```
asadmin create-protocol --securityenabled=false http-redirect
asadmin create-http-redirect --redirect-port 8181 --secure-redirect true http-redirect
asadmin create-protocol --securityenabled=false pu-protocol
asadmin create-protocol-finder --protocol pu-protocol --target-protocol http-listener-2 --classname com.sun.grizzly.config.HttpProtocolFinder http-finder
asadmin create-protocol-finder --protocol pu-protocol --target-protocol http-redirect --classname com.sun.grizzly.config.HttpProtocolFinder http-redirect
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.http-listener-1.protocol=pu-protocol
```

I am unable to deploy an .ear containing several .wars and ejbs. One of the packages contains a web service that seems to be causing an exception on deployment.

```
[#|2012-05-17T10:30:28.118+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=96;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:193)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:698)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:690)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeFinalWsdlUrl(WebServiceEndpoint.java:753)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.doWebServicesDeployment(WebServicesDeployer.java:634)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:184)
    ... 62 more
|#]

[#|2012-05-17T10:30:28.184+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=96;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while preparing the app
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:193)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:698)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:690)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeFinalWsdlUrl(WebServiceEndpoint.java:753)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.doWebServicesDeployment(WebServicesDeployer.java:634)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:184)
    ... 62 more
|#]
```

This package deploys fine without port unification so it seems something has caused a problem in glassfish. 
Has anyone else encountered this or know of how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually this turned out to be due to trying to deploy an application that doesn't force a web service to use SSL.

To solve this I needed to include a glassfish-ejb-jar.xml (for ***.war*** files with web services) or a sun-ejb-jar.xml (for ***ejb modules*** with web services).

**Example glassfish-ejb-jar.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//
DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 EJB 3.1//EN" 
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-ejb-jar_3_1-1.dtd">
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <ejb>
            <ejb-name>MyEJB</ejb-name>
            <webservice-endpoint>
                <port-component-name>MyWebService</port-component-name>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </webservice-endpoint>
        </ejb>
    </enterprise-beans>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

**Example sun-ejb-jar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-ejb-jar PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD 
Application Server 9.0 EJB 3.0//EN' 
'http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-ejb-jar_3_0-0.dtd'>
<sun-ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <ejb>
            <ejb-name>MyEJB</ejb-name>
            <webservice-endpoint>
                <port-component-name>MyWebService</port-component-name>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </webservice-endpoint>
        </ejb>
    </enterprise-beans>
</sun-ejb-jar>
```